# Best way to split large string in linux with single character shift

Tags: linux, string

I have a large file that contains a single example string 
ABCDEFGHI  (example length 10 characters).
Actual file length could be millions of characters.

I would like to split the string into multiple lines with a predetermined length but while splitting the character is shifted 1 at a time. This means after splits the 
no. of lines = string length - split size + 1

Example if I split it by 3 character at a time then desired output

```
ABC
BCD
CDE
DEF
...
```

If I split by 4 characters then

```
ABCD
BCDE
CDEF
DEFG
```

What is the best way of doing this split using shell commands or scripting?

Thanks for any hints

Comment: there is more than one way to do it, the best one being dependent of your context. The awk stuff is pretty neat for most gnu based unices, python stuff is portable but more expensive...

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
gawk -v FS="" '{
    r=3 # Set the length
    s=1 # Set the start point
    while(s<=NF-r+1) { 
        for (i=s;i<r+s;i++) { 
            printf $i 
        }
        s++
        print ""
     }
}'
```

#### Test:

```
$ echo "ABCDEFGHI" | gawk -v FS="" '{r=4; s=1; while(s<=NF-r+1) { for (i=s;i<r+s;i++) printf $i ; s++; print ""}}'
ABCD
BCDE
CDEF
DEFG
EFGH
FGHI
$ echo "ABCDEFGHI" | gawk -v FS="" '{r=3; s=1; while(s<=NF-r+1) { for (i=s;i<r+s;i++) printf $i ; s++; print ""}}'
ABC
BCD
CDE
DEF
EFG
FGH
GHI
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with `sed` (in `bash`):

`GNU sed`:

```
sed -r ':a;s/([^\n])([^\n]{'$(( n-1 ))'})([^\n])/\1\2\n\2\3/;ta' filename
```

or `POSIX sed` (I think):

```
sed ':a;s/\([^\n]\)\([^\n]\{'$(( n-1 ))'\}\)\([^\n]\)/\1\2\n\2\3/;ta' filename
```

Output:

- with `n=3`:

  ```
  ABC
  BCD
  CDE
  DEF
  EFG
  FGH
  GHI
  ```
- with `n=4`:

  ```
  ABCD
  BCDE
  CDEF
  DEFG
  EFGH
  FGHI
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk-based option, involving `substr`

```
echo 'abcdefgh' |
awk -v limit=3  'BEGIN{FS=""}; 
{value=$0; for (i=1; i<= NF-limit +1; ++i) print substr(value, i, limit)}'

abc
bcd
cde
def
efg
fgh
ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

using python you could write something like this:

```
import itertools

filename = "myfile"
length = 4
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    out = ''
    # get your input character by character
    for c in itertools.chain.from_iterable(f):
        # append it to your output buffer
        out += c
        # if your buffer is more than N characters, remove the first char
        if len(out) > length:
            out = out[1:]
        # if your buffer is exactly N characters, print it out (or do something else)
        if len(out) is length:
            print out
    # if the last iteration was less than N characters, print it out (or do something else)
    if len(out) < length:
        print out
```

where file is a string containing the full path of your string. You can use also `raw_input()` instead of `open()/read()`. There sure is a neat solution using awk, but I would need to RTFM to tell you how to do it.

Whatever your solution is, this algorithm is a good way to do it, as you always keep only up to N+1 characters for the buffer, plus one character for the new read. So the complexity of this algorithm is linear (`O(n)`) to the input character stream.

Comment: `file` -> `filename` so that you don't shadow the `file` type. Also `out` could be a *list* characters that are joined when printed (appending to a string is costly).

Comment: Last, but not least, your code does not work, it prints a single character. Your looping with `for` over a string containing a 1 character.

Comment: well, fixed the file shadowing, and the looping over characters. You were right, but that was easily fixed. All I anyway wanted to show off, is the algorithm's idea.

Answer (score 0):

While I generally dislike bringing in heavyweight scripting languages like this, python makes this pretty much trivial

```
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from os import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1])
s = sys.argv[2]

while len(s) > 0:
    print s[:n]
    s = s[1:]

$ python test.py 3 abcdef
abc
bcd
cde
def
ef
f
$ python test.py 4 abcdef
abcd
bcde
cdef
def
ef
f
$
```

If you want to stop once you run out of characters, you can change the `while` condition to `len(s) >= n`.

Comment: I made a similar mistake in interpreting the question. OP wants to keep looping his text by shifting one character. The delimiter can be predefined.

Comment: your solution would lead to memory exhaustion with billions of characters. A streamed input is a better solution. ;-)

Comment: @Kevin Python looks so clean. Just one small change. The `while` loop should continue until `length of the string passed - predetermined length + 1`. See last three lines of second test and last two lines of first test.